# How do I put my scraped data into a data frame

Tags: text, nlp

Please i need help, am having trouble trying to put my scraped data into a data frame that has 3 columns i.e. date, source and keywords extracted from each scraped website for further text analysis, my code is borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/users/12229253/foreverlearning and is given below:

```
from newspaper import Article
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
urls = ['https://dailypost.ng/2022/02/02/securing-nigeria-duty-of-all-tiers-of-government-oyo-senator-balogun/', 'https://guardian.ng/news/declare-bandits-as-terrorists-senate-tells-buhari/', 'https://www.thisdaylive.com/index.php/2021/10/24/when-will-fg-declare-bandits-as-terrorists/', 'https://punchng.com/rep-wants-buhari-to-name-lawmaker-sponsoring-terrorism/', 'https://punchng.com/national-assembly-plans-to-meet-us-congress-over-875m-weapons-deal-stoppage/']
results = {}
for url in urls:
    article = Article(url)
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()
    results[url] = article
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    article = results[url]
    print(article.authors)
    print(article.publish_date)
    print(article.keywords)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with it and here is how you can make it into a data frame. Assuming that you wanted to use pandas in the first place:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd

from newspaper import Article


nltk.download('punkt')


urls = ['https://dailypost.ng/2022/02/02/securing-nigeria-duty-of-all-tiers-of-government-oyo-senator-balogun/', 'https://guardian.ng/news/declare-bandits-as-terrorists-senate-tells-buhari/', 'https://www.thisdaylive.com/index.php/2021/10/24/when-will-fg-declare-bandits-as-terrorists/', 'https://punchng.com/rep-wants-buhari-to-name-lawmaker-sponsoring-terrorism/', 'https://punchng.com/national-assembly-plans-to-meet-us-congress-over-875m-weapons-deal-stoppage/']

    # create a data frame with the needed columns
saved_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Source', 'KeyWords'])
    # put into a data frame that has 3 columns i.e. date, source and keywords
def add_data_to_df(urls, saved_data):
    for url in urls: # process each url separately
        article = Article(url)
        article.download()
        article.parse()
        article.nlp()
        # create a row with the data you need using attributes
        record = {'Date': article.publish_date, 'Source': url, 'KeyWords': article.keywords}
        # append info about each url as a new row
        saved_data = saved_data.append(record, ignore_index = True)

    return saved_data
```

Now, when you run this function
`add_data_to_df(urls, saved_data)`, you should see a data frame with contents similar to the ones I got below during testing:

Date    Source  KeyWords
0   2022-02-02 00:00:00 https://dailypost.ng/2022/02/02/securing-niger...   [nigeria, securing, oyo, state, senator, prote...
1   2021-09-30 04:25:24+00:00   https://guardian.ng/news/declare-bandits-as-te...   [shutdown, terrorists, nigeria, guardian, decl...
2   2021-10-24 00:00:00 https://www.thisdaylive.com/index.php/2021/10/...   [terrorists, nigerian, declare, state, militar...
3   2021-10-05 14:41:48+00:00   https://punchng.com/rep-wants-buhari-to-name-l...   [president, buhari, house, national, lawmaker,...
4   2021-07-31 00:30:47+00:00   https://punchng.com/national-assembly-plans-to...   [plans, congress, deal, nigeria, nigerian, rig...

(Sorry for the format, I am showing the output as plain text since I am not allowed to attach screenshots, but you will have a nice pandas format)

**Edit**: adding a function to save the data frame to a csv file. Note that this one of the shortest ways of doing this and it will save the file to the current working directory, i.e., where you are executing your code:

```
# this function saves given data to csv    
def save_to_csv(saved_data):
        saved_data.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, sep=',')

# process the articles and create a csv
save_to_csv(add_data_to_df(urls, saved_data))
```

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply, thanks a lot. But when i ran the code it says: NameError: name 'article' is not defined

Comment: Hi got it now had run the code in block, however, i want to save it as a csv file also, pls could you help

Comment: @BashirAbubakar, you are welcome! To mark this answer as accepted since it worked for you, please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to green. That way people with the same problem will know that this solutions works. If you need to save the output to a cvs you will need to add another function that does this using 'to_csv'. I will add this function to the main answer.

Comment: i deeply appreciate your help in solving my challenge, one more final help pls , i totally forgot that a key information (variable) is missing in my dataset, that is the "title of the articles", meaning altogether a data set of 4 variables (columns)  consisting of date, source, title and keywords. Pls help me on how to also add (scrape) the titles of the articles so that i can integrate it into the code, once again thanks a lot, am grateful

Comment: @ Ascandance, I also noticed that some of the articles links do not download or open or time out how do i skip them?

Comment: @BashirAbubakar, you can expand the dataset and add as many columns as you would like by adding new column names when initializing the dataframe in 'saved_data', then modifying the dict 'record': the key is the name of the new column , the value is the new attribute you are adding (article title in this case). E.g., for the title column add  'Title': article.title  to the record variable, then 'Title' column to the list of columns in saved_data.

Comment: @BashirAbubakar the articles will not load from time to time but they load 9 out of 10 times for me. If you want to handle such cases you would have to write quite complex code to handle such cases when articles time out which would be a different question on this website